# A Tensor Calculation with Braids

Tags: representation-theory, tensors, knot-invariants, braid-groups

I am trying to follow the derivation of the Jone's Polynomial from a braid representation presented in chapter 2 of Ohtsuki's *Quantum Invariants*.

The representation of the braid $b$ with $n$ strands is a linear operator (which we treat as a matrix after choosing some basis) on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ is $\psi_n(b)$. Let $\sigma_i$ denote the crossing of the $i$-th strand under the $(i+1)$-th strand for $i \in \{1, \cdots , n-1 \}$. Then, $$\psi_n(\sigma_i)= \pmatrix {1 & 0\\ 0 &1}^{\bigotimes (i-1)}\otimes R \otimes \pmatrix {1 & 0\\ 0 &1}^{\bigotimes (n-i-1)},$$ where, after many calculations (which I omit) having to do with the requirements on $R$ in order for it to properly represent the braid generator, we find that $$R= \pmatrix {t^{1/2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & t & 0\\
0 & t & t^{1/2}-t^{3/2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & t^{1/2}}.$$

We want the trace of a braid representation to be invariant under Markov moves, but this is not the case. So we introduce an auxiliary matrix $$h= \pmatrix {t^{-1/2} & 0\\ 0 & t^{1/2}},$$ which allows for $\mathrm{trace}(h^{\otimes n}\cdot\psi_n(b))$ invariant under both Markov moves.

**This is what I don't understand:** I can figure that $$\mathrm{trace}_2((\pmatrix {1 & 0\\ 0 &1} \otimes h)\cdot R) = \pmatrix {1 & 0\\ 0 &1}$$ by direct calculation. I do not understand the last two 
 of the following lines which justify the invariance of the trace. $$\begin{align} \mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n+1)}\cdot\psi_{n+1}(\sigma_n b))  & = \mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n +1)}\cdot (\pmatrix {1 & 0\\ 0 &1}^{\bigotimes (n-1)} \otimes R ) \cdot \psi_{n+1}(b))\tag{1}\\ & = \mathrm{trace}(h^{\otimes n}\cdot\psi_n(b))\tag{2}. \end{align} $$ Going from (1) to (2) should use the fact above about the partial trace, but I don't see how. A more explicit derivation of this would be **much appreciated**. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have really been struggling with understanding this... I guess I should just do a concrete calculation for small $n$.

Comment: $h^{\otimes(n+1)}  \cdot (I_2^{\otimes(n-1)}  \otimes R)  = (h\cdot I_2) ^{\otimes (n-1)} \otimes (h^{\otimes 2} \cdot R) $

Comment: Now $\psi_{n+1} (b) = \psi_{n} (b) \otimes I_2$

Comment: So we just need find $\text{trace } (h^{\otimes 2} \otimes R) $, which you can try and it gives $h$.

Comment: Note:  $I_2$ is just the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Btw, I saw this in >math

Comment: @wilsonw I agree with all of the things that you have put here in these comments, but my dense self can't really see how this leads to the conclusion. Btw if you make this an answer I will upvote and accept it. I'm glad I posted on >math in that case. This helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) = (AC)\otimes (BD)$.
Now
$$h^{\otimes(n+1)}\cdot(
I_2
^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes R) = (h\otimes h\otimes \cdots\otimes h )\cdot(I_2\otimes I_2\otimes \cdots \otimes I_2 \otimes R) = (h\cdot I_2)^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes (h^{\otimes 2}\cdot R) = h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes (h^{\otimes 2}\cdot R)$$

Now we plug it back to the LHS of equation $(1)$.
$$\mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n+1)}\cdot\psi_{n+1}(\sigma_n b))  = \mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n +1)}\cdot (I_2^{\bigotimes (n-1)} \otimes R ) \cdot \psi_{n+1}(b)) =\mathrm{trace}(( h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes (h^{\otimes 2}\cdot R))\cdot \psi_{n+1}(b)) $$

Then use the fact that $\psi_{n+1}(b) = \psi_{n}(b)\otimes I_2$ because $b$ is a braid with $n$ strands only, so the $(n+1)^{st}$ term in the tensor product is just $I_2$:
$$\mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n+1)}\cdot\psi_{n+1}(\sigma_n b)) =\mathrm{trace}( (h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes (h^{\otimes 2}\cdot R))\cdot (\psi_n(b)\otimes I_2))  $$

Now this middle term can be calculated directly:
$$h^{\otimes 2} = \pmatrix{t^{-1}\\ & 1 \\ & & 1 \\ & & & t}$$
When multiplied by $R$ this gives
$$B = \pmatrix {t^{-1/2}&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&t^{1/2}-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}}$$

Now we break this matrix $B$ into the matrix $h\otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and a traceless part
$$B = h\otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + \pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}}$$

Plugging back in gives
$$\mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes (n+1)}\cdot\psi_{n+1}(\sigma_n b)) =\mathrm{trace}( (h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes ( h\otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + \pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}})\cdot (\psi_n(b)\otimes I_2)) = \mathrm{trace}( (h^{\otimes n}\cdot \psi_n(b))\otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}) + \mathrm{trace}( (h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes \pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}})\cdot (\psi_n(b)\otimes I_2))  $$

Using $\mathrm{trace}(A\otimes B) = \mathrm{trace}(A)\mathrm{trace}(B)$, the first term gives
$$\mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes n}\cdot \psi_n(b))\mathrm{trace}( \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}) = \mathrm{trace}( h^{\otimes n}\cdot \psi_n(b)) $$

For the second term we have no way out besides writing the matrices out. However, note that the matrix $(h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes \pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}})$ is block-diagonal, and since we are only concerned with traces, we can focus only on the $(i,i)^{th}$ block entry. Thus we only need consider the product
$$x_{ii}\pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}}\pmatrix {y_{2i-1,2i-1}&0&y_{2i-1,2i}&0 \\ 0& y_{2i-1,2i-1}&0 & y_{2i-1,2i}\\ y_{2i,2i-1}&0& y_{2i,2i}&0 \\ 0 & y_{2i,2i-1}& 0&  y_{2i,2i}}$$
where $h^{\otimes (n-1)} = (x_{ij})$ and $\psi_n(b)=(y_{kl})$

Multiplying out gives
$$x_{ii}\pmatrix{0&*&*&*\\*&0&*&*\\*&*&-t^{3/2}y_{2i,2i}&* \\ *&*&*&t^{3/2}y_{2i,2i}}$$
which is traceless.
Thus each block on the main diagonal of the matrix $M = (h^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes \pmatrix {0&0&0&0 \\ 0& 0 &t & 0\\ 0&t&-t^{3/2}&0 \\ 0 &0& 0& t^{3/2}})\cdot (\psi_n(b)\otimes I_2)$ is traceless. The matrix $M$ is thus traceless.